# REST API testing common issues

Tags: rest, testing

I have recently started testing rest based web services. I am wondering what are common issues faced while testing them.

I generally look for

1. response status (http code is among 200/400/500)
2. response headers (cache control, response type, content length )
3. if expected  fields / values are present in json response.

I want to know what else to look for and issues in general while testing rest based web services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a very broad question but, here are the things that I look for while testing rest API's:

1. Response codes, Response headers
2. Check if Authentication/Authorization is correct based on user privileges
3. Check to see if the supplied value can break the output
4. Intentionally pass different Data-Type values to see if proper handling is done or not
5. Use load testing tools to see how many concurrent requests an API can handle

Again these are just a few things that will depend on the type of API you are building. Feel free to add more as you progress.

Comment: If you think that this is too broad, why are you answering it? Gaining Reputation?

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ There are many questions which are broad but still it will be helpful for users like us, thus according to me there is no point in closing those question.

Comment: @HarshalBulsara - Consider this scenario. We have N api calls. Say, only 1% of the API users get read timeout for only one of the N api calls. We know for sure that the users are making valid api calls. How would we debug this issue ? Is there a general list of things we can check ? [Eg. If API uses load balancer, check if all instances are running ? Maybe unlucky user's requests are going to a stopped instance. 
If all instances are running, then check if their server logs have any errors ? etc...]

Comment: @testerjoe2 For testing purpose, just log all the API calls in some file with an incremented number and check for load testing, you might get the scenario where it is failing additionally you can check your database profiler as well to see if your DB is fast enough to process the request

Comment: Most of the time we put app servers in load balances but both are pointing to same database, many time it happens that DB is not able to handle that load.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, but let me share a few that aren't even specifically API issues but a full API integration test will help find it.

We did an integration API test where a publisher's product listing endpoint was hit, and then we randomly picked 100 of those products. Every few weeks we would find a bunch of bad product ID's. How was it possible? They would update the database but the product listing endpoint was cached and had bad information for hours until it was refreshed automatically.

Another time we found an e-commerce company in Brooklyn that, on average, had 3,500 products out of their 50k+ were missing a category. This meant 3,500 products not showing up if you browsed by categories, and potential lost sales.

We have a whole case study of this stuff on our website. Weird and unexpected stuff happens all the time. Test for everything and catch as much as you can. Every object in the payload should be verified, it may seem like overkill but there are platforms that can do all that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are suggestions based on my experience while testing Restful APIs.

1. Make sure that you are validating proprietary headers if you are using with your APIs.
2. Confirm that you are including correct location header in the response so that Rest API caller can use that for verification or for subsequent calls.
3. Check that location header protocol is correct i.e as per your design. (http/https). It's very important for subsequent calls.